# Just to know the value of a variable using xdebug in vim

Tags: vim, xdebug

I'm new to debugging using xdebug (or any other software), so I installed this [plugin](https://github.com/ludovicPelle/vim-xdebug), and I followed these [instructions](http://2bits.com/articles/using-vim-and-xdebug-dbgp-for-debugging-drupal-or-any-php-application.html#comment-1490) just to know the value of variable. So for checking the value of a variable I think these are the steps:

- Create the breakpoing
- Press F5 in vim
- Press F5 in browser
- Press F4 in vim
- Move the cursor to the variable
- Press F12 to check the value of the variable

It works ok, but for me these are too much steps just to avoid the typical `var_dump($variable);die;` line.

Is there anything am I doing wrong? is there any other quicker way to check the value of a variable?

Comment: Debugging is a tedious process. IDEs typically offer the most streamlined experience by doing eveything in one tool: editing, running, debugging… even then, you still have some clicking to do. Vim is an editor, not an IDE: the editor, the interface to the debugger, the debugger itself, the browser are all separate tools with varying and limited levels of integration: of course you'll do a lot of clicking. Did you consider using an IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vim is first and foremost a text editor; due to its versality and extensibility, you can make it more IDE-like, though.

If you're a beginner (with debugging) and you want a comfortable, easy experience, I suggest using a fully-fledged IDE instead. (You can still integrate Vim into your workflow for the act of text editing; e.g. I open files in Vim from my IDE with a simple shortcut.)

If you really want to avoid an IDE (for whatever reason) and stick with simple, command line-oriented tools, I'd suggest learning *xdebug* standalone first, and only then try to integrate it with Vim.